# Volley onResponse work after twice click

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I need a little help :)

I'm using volley on my Android app and I wrote this codes.

```
    public String validateCredentials(final String email, final String password) {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST,
            LOGIN_URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject serverResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.d("Result: ", serverResponse.getString("result"));
                responseServ = serverResponse.getString("result");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(email, password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    return responseServ;
}
```

When I click the button `Log.d("Result: ", serverResponse.getString("result"));` this code is work but `return responseServ;` is not send any data on first click.

My button onClick code is

```
Toast.makeText(activity, authModel.validateCredentials(email, password), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How do I solve this problem?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volley is asynchronous aka you make the call, then later the callback is executed (Log.d() part). But you are also synchronously returning value which is empty the first time, and only the second time return values. 
Have in mind that the second time it returns the first result.

What you have to do is do all your work in `onResponse()`

PS: As you want to keep MVP pattern you can- Define callback `Interface` and pass it to `validateCredentials(final String email, final String password, final OnLoginComplete callback)`  and then in `onResponse()` callback.loginComplete()

Comment: I understand but I trying to use mvp system. And this codes are in my loginModel class. I'm get data from in model with presenterImplents and if result is success then user can login. If , I have to do is do all my work in onResponse() then this is not be a MVP system. I'm I right?

Comment: @AhmetTalutTasgiran ive edited my answer with how i handle it. See if this helps

Comment: Thanks. I finally did it :D Because an hour ago I don't know how use callback interface system :D (Sorry for my English)